# Как спарсить все страницы сайта , загружая только одну страницу

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4, scrapy

Сайт https://www.livelib.ru/reader/LushbaughPizzicato/read/ автоматически подгружает 20 книг, если нажать "показать еще"  он подгрузит еще 20 книг, как можно сделать, чтобы подгрузились сразу все книги?

И потом этот результат обработать с помощью beautifulsoup?

Как я понимаю в Network , с помощью getcountbooks в header: content-legth  20 задается количество загружаемых книг, но как передать это на сайт и изменить 20 на другое число я не понимаю.

Пс заранее спасибо)

Comment: если разработчики сайта не предусмотрели такой возможности (а скорее всего они ее не предусмотрели), то никак. Вам нужно открыть все страницы по очереди и обработать каждую из них по очереди. Но это ведь довольно просто, подставляйте в адрес пагинации числа по очереди и все. До тех пор, пока не получите пустую страницу, на которой не будет книг.

Comment: "Как я понимаю ... в header: content-legth 20 задается количество загружаемых книг"... неправильно понимаете ;) это - объем данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в тело запроса подставить количество возвращаемых записей через поле `per_page`.

По умолчанию, там 20 объектов, в качестве примера подставил туда 100 и пришло 54 элемента, т.е. все

Пример:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.livelib.ru/reader/LushbaughPizzicato/read/listview/smalllist'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}
data = {
    'page_no': 1,
    'per_page': 100,
    'is_new_design': "ll2019",
    'is_prev': "false"
}
rs = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(rs)

data_json = rs.json()
object_ids = data_json['object_ids']
print(len(object_ids), object_ids)
# 54 [1000518262, 1002753859, 1000330921, ..., 1000593383, 1002885672]
```

---

**Думаю, имеет смысл рассказать как это написал.**

1. Нашел запрос, отправленный при клике на кнопку "показать еще"
2. Посмотрел на тело запроса
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. В заголовках запроса посмотрел на `Content-Type`, от этого зависит какой атрибут использовать для отправки тела запроса: `data`, `json` или `files`. А `x-www-form-urlencoded` это `data`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Добавил в заголовок запроса `User-Agent` и `X-Requested-With`, чтобы сервер принял его и вернул ожидаемый `json`

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но у меня несколько вопросов 1 - что вы используете за программу для определения тела запроса? 2 - получаемый запрос я хочу обработать в beautifulsoup, а как json преобразовать обратно в парсер? или можно как нибудь по json искать нужные мне тэги?

Comment: @44_88, это инспектор браузера, открывается на F12. В том json есть куски html, вот их и скормите beautifulsoup, `data_json` это просто питоничий объект, словарь, поэтому через работу с ним получите нужные -- получайте значение по ключу, работаете с значением и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример с моего бота. За формат прошу не пинать. через пару часу буду у ноута, отформатирую как принято.
В данном примере парсится вес табака, что есть в наличии. Если обнаруживает пагинацию - берет ссылку на след страничку и рекурсивно работает.

```py
def __get_weight_kalyan_od_ua(url) -> set:
    weight = set()
    logger.info(f'Переходим по {url} и парсим её')
    try:
        soup = __get_soup(url) #получаем все тело сайта
    except:
        return weight #если ошибка при запросе, возвращаем пустой обьект
    logger.info(f'Получаем ссылку на следующую страницу с табаками в категории')
    next_page = __parse_next_page(soup, 'ul', 'class', 'pagination') #парсим элемент с пагинацией
    next_page = next_page.find('a', text='>') if next_page else next_page #если есть кнопка след страницы, сохраняем ее иначе None
    logger.info(f'Парсим все продукты на странице')
    products = __parse_products(soup, 'a', 'class', 'products__item-title') #список табаков
    logger.info(f'Проходим по каждому продукту')
    for product in products:
        logger.info(f'Парсим есть ли он в наличии, если нет - переходим к следующему')
        if not __parse_available(product.parent.parent, 'mark', 'class', 'products__item-mark--nocatch'):
            logger.info(f'Пропускаем')
            continue
        logger.info(f'Парсим вес продукта из названия')
        weight.add(__parse_weight(product.text))
    logger.info(f'Пока есть следующая страница, повторяем процес парсинга веса')
    if next_page: # если есть элемент след страницы
        weight.update(__get_weight_kalyan_od_ua(next_page['href'])) #рекурсивно вызываем функцию ещё раз
    return weight
```